# Django file_resubmit doesn't work in a templates view

Tags: django, forms

So I have the problem where for a form that has an ImageField, (rendered using forms.py in Django) whenever the validation error comes up, maybe due to miss matching passwords etc. the ImageField get cleared.

After some googling, I found a module called `file_resubmit` . This seems to have worked well for many people however for some reason it doesn't work for me...

Docs of [file_resubmit](https://github.com/un1t/django-file-resubmit)

I did as their docs said but doesn't seem to work for me.

I'm my settings.py ...

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    .
    .
    'file_resubmit',
]


CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
    },
    "file_resubmit": {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
        "LOCATION": '/tmp/file_resubmit'
    }
}
```

In my forms.py...

```
from file_resubmit.admin import AdminResubmitImageWidget


class DriverRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    mobile = forms.CharField(min_length=10)
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'off'}), help_text="You need to be a minimum age of 18 to register with us")
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[("M","Male"), ("F", "Female")])
    district = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CITY)
    nic_number = forms.CharField(label="NIC number", min_length=10)
    license = forms.ImageField(label="License picture")
    your_picture = forms.ImageField(help_text="A picture of yourself so that we know who you are")

    class Meta:
        model = ProfileDriver
        fields = ('mobile', 'gender', 'district', 'nic_number', 'license', 'date_of_birth', 'your_picture')
        widgets = {
            "license":AdminResubmitImageWidget,
            "your_picture":AdminResubmitImageWidget,
        }
```

And just in case my models.py..

```
class ProfileDriver (models.Model):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=13, unique=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(validators=[dob_authorized])
    gender = models.CharField(choices=[("M","Male"), ("F", "Female")], default="M", max_length=6)
    district = models.CharField(choices=CITY, default="CMD", max_length=11)
    nic_number = models.CharField(max_length=13, unique=True)
    license = models.ImageField(upload_to="driverLicense")
    your_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="driverImages")
    total_income = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__ (self):
        return f"{self.user}"
```

And views.py...

```
def driver_register(request):
    if not request.user.username:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form1 = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
            form2 = DriverRegisterForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
                email = form1.cleaned_data.get("email")
                if not User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                    user = form1.save()
                    profile = form2.save()
                    profile.user = user
                    profile.save()
                    return redirect ('login')
                else:
                    messages.warning(request, f"An account under the email {email} already exists. Please sign in!")
        else:
            form1 = UserRegistrationForm()
            form2 = DriverRegisterForm()

        return render(request, 'user/driverRegister.html', {"form1":form1, "form2":form2})

    else:
        email = request.user.email
        messages.warning(request, f"You are already logged in as {email}!")
        return redirect ('home')
```

I am not too sure why this doesn't work but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

**EDIT**

Once after doing such alterations I get this now when my form gets a validation error.
[image]

Over here now the name of the file is shown below the button but when I submit it, it says that the file is unavailable and that I need to add it.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the fields yourself in the form i.e. `license = forms.ImageField(...)`, etc. this means that the model form will not be automatically generating this field since it is a *declared field*. Hence when you define the widgets for these fields in the `Meta` class it will never be used.

Instead you want to specify the widget on the form fields themselves (or don't define the form fields and let the form generate them automatically):

```py
class DriverRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    license = forms.ImageField(label="License picture", widget=AdminResubmitImageWidget())
    your_picture = forms.ImageField(help_text="A picture of yourself so that we know who you are", widget=AdminResubmitImageWidget())
    ...
    
    class Meta:
        model = ProfileDriver
        fields = ('mobile', 'gender', 'district', 'nic_number', 'license', 'date_of_birth', 'your_picture')
        # Don't define widgets here
```

Comment: Hey @AbdulAzizBarkat thanks for your comment, I have got somewhere but it doesn't seem to work perfectly, please see the last part of my question which I have edited and provided a screenshot as well